# Regarding the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes: what are the main differences?

Tags: koma-script, document-classes, article, report

What are the main differences between the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes?

I am interested in the following:

1. visual differences in the final document;
2. differences in the way the document must be coded;
3. differences between the standard classes and their `KOMA-Script` equivalents; and
4. any other significant differences.

Comment: It would be great if answers could possibly also address the memoir class as it seems to be quite similar as well.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

As Schweinebacke has noted, there are two kind of differences: a) differences in availability of commands and environments b) differences in the default settings. Only the latter may be changed easily using options and commands.

Differences with regard to available commands and environments:

- `book` and `report` feature the `\chapter` sectioning command, while `article` doesn't.
- In `book` and `report`, `\appendix` will cause `\chapter`s to be typeset as "Appendix X"  instead of "Chapter X". For `article`, this isn't applicable.
- `book` and `report` will start a new page for `\part`s , while `article` won't.
- `book` offers the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` commands to control page numbering (`Roman` for the front matter, `arabic` elsewhere)  and numbering of sectioning titles (no numbering in the front and back matter), while `report` and `article` don't.
- `book` *doesn't* offer the `abstract` environment, while `report` and `article` *do*.

Differences with regard to default settings:

- The `book` class uses the `twoside` class option (which means different margins and headers/footers for even and odd pages), while `report` and `article` use `oneside`.
- `book` uses `openright` (new parts and chapters start on "right" pages, adding a blank page before if necessary), while `report` uses `openany`. (Note that "right" means an odd page in `twoside` mode, but any page in `oneside` mode.) For `article`, the distinction between `openright` and `openany` isn't applicable.
- `book` uses the `headings` pagestyle for non-chapter-starting pages, while `report` and `article` always use `plain`.
- `book` and `report` use `titlepage` (the title page and -- if applicable -- the `abstract` environment will be typeset on pages of their own), while `article` uses `notitlepage`.
- For `book` and `report`, the lowest-level sectioning command which is numbered and incorporated into the table of contents is `\subsection`, while for `article` it is `\subsubsection`.
- `book` and `report` will use the arguments of `\chapter`s  and `\section`s for running headings (if such headings are present), while `article` will use `\section`s and `\subsection`s.
- `book` and `report` will number floats (figures, tables etc.), equations, and footnotes per chapter, while `article` will number them continuously. Note that footnotes -- even when numbered per chapter -- do not feature a chapter prefix.
- `book` and `report` will use `\bibname` (which defaults to "Bibliography") for the heading of bibliographic references, while `article` will use `\refname` (which defaults to "References").

All of the above is valid for `scrbook` v. `scrreprt` vs. `scrartcl` as well.

Comment: `twoside` vs. `oneside`, `openright` vs. `openany`, `headings` vs. `plain` are differences in the default settings only. These may be changed by options or commands. The differences about `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` and `abstract` are differences in availability of commands/environments. So they may be more important.

Comment: The `openright` option forces chapters to start always on *odd* pages.

Comment: Which one would you use for a thesis?

Comment: @skan: depends. As is written above, `book` does not support the `abstract` environment, so if you need that, you either have to use `report` or put in a replacement yourself. Similarly for other features. There are also various thesis templates/class files floating around on the internet if you don't have strict formatting requirements (or maybe there is already one for your university). If you need to write your own and have requirements, you may consider using the [`memoir` class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).

Comment: Would I need a longer time to learn (and write the thesis with) regular Latex and add some extras or to learn memoir (or Koma) ?

Comment: @WillieWong I've read I can use \chapter{abstract} to add the abstract. What is the disadvantage?

Comment: @skan: you can also just use `\textbf{Abstract}` and type under it. If you are happy with how things looks: go ahead, knock yourself out.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/mori/mori.pdf  page 7, please?.  It explains that we need to define some lines on the preamble.  Why do they do it so complex instead of just your solution?

Comment: What about using the "thesis class" or "classical thesis"? What is the adantage of doing so?

Comment: @lockstep you can add usage difference of these also.