# How do I put chapters into a LaTeX document?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, document-classes

I used the following LaTeX tag to make a chapter

```
\chapter{title here}
```

but it did not compile. The LaTeX compiler was talking about

```
Undefined control sequence
```

How can I get over this error?

Comment: Not all document classes support chapters (article, in particular). You need to provide a minimal working example of your document for this to be answered any further.

Comment: Hi its quite hard to say what´s going on with that little information. Make sure that you use a documentclass which provides `\chapter` such as `report` or `book`

Comment: Please provide a [Mimimum Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043). In your case minimum code that demonstrates the problem and compiles as it should when the offending `\chapter{...}` is commented out.

Comment: thanks mike and bloodworks. Your solution solved my problem

Comment: @MikeRenfro As you commented first, please turn your comment into an answer. Otherwise, we'll probably close the question.

Comment: @lockstep comment converted to answer, as requested.

Comment: For a general overview of differences between the standard document classes see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/book-vs-report-vs-article-document-class

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not all document classes support chapters -- in particular, the `article` standard class does not, while `book` and `report` do. You need to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your document for this to be answered any further.