# Type of file to select for writing Math Thesis if I use latex from Kile

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, thesis

if I write a math. thesis using latex from Kile, then, while opening a new file in Kile, what is the option should I choose: article/book/report? Thank you!

Comment: You should look at the ams classes, too. E.g. amsbook rather than plain book since this will automatically get you a bunch of maths set up. But it depends really on the format required by your institution.

Comment: **http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/type-of-file-to-select-for-writing-math-thesis-if-i-use-latex-from-kile**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding the \`book\`, \`report\`, and \`article\` document classes: what are the main differences?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/regarding-the-book-report-and-article-document-classes-what-are-the-mai)

Answer (score 2):

`book` is the most appropriate from the 3, as it provides you with `\chapter`s.

If I were you, I would also consider the [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) class, which provides lots of customization options and is very popular for writing thesis and books.