# Separate styles for section headers in table of contents and body

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

I'm looking to have different 'styles' (not sure if this is the right word) for my section headers depending on whether they're listed in the TOC or the body.
That's probably not clear, so let me demonstrate.

In the body, I'd like to see:

```
Article I. Intro 
....
Article II. Methods
....
```

But in the TOC I'd like to see

```
I. Intro .......... 5
II. Methods ........10
```

without the "Article" bit.

Right now, I'm using this to set the section headers:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Article \Roman{section}.}
```

I should mention I'm using the `article` class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Have you considered using the `report` class for this?

Comment: Don't change that command as you did. You can use another word to insert in the TOC. Just write `\section[to appear in TOC]{to appear in the body}`.

Comment: @Sigur I think what you're suggesting is `\section[Intro]{Article I. Intro}`. But then the TOC shows `1 Intro ... 5` but the body shows `1 Article I. Intro` which is not what I want. I could use `/section*` but then I need to `\addcontentsline` all of the time.

Comment: @MarioS.E. I'm unclear on how `report` would help. Doesn't this just add an extra chapter level?

Comment: @user1591288 You can check the differences here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/book-vs-report-vs-article-document-class

Comment: You have to lead with two different things: the formating of section header and the type of section counter. You have to change it to Roman and insert an extra word in front of the section name.

Comment: @Sigur thank you for being so patient with me. I am still a little confused. What did my `\renewcommand` command do? Did it format the section headers, or change the type of section counter? If you could provide me with an example, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: `\thesection` prints the section counter. You are redefining that counter to print a word and the counter. This is not a good idea. For example, try `\section{title}\label{key} In section \ref{key}...`  with you redefined command.

Comment: @Sigur OK, now I understand why I don't want to use the command I tried above. What's my solution? Ultimately, it seems that I need to change the way the section headers are generated (both the work "Article" and the counter from `arabic` to `Roman`) but not let this affect the TOC. I'm sorry -- very slow tonight.

Comment: Look here for `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `titlesec` package was used to add "Article" before the section number and the dot after the number. The `tocloft` package was used to add the dot after the number in the table of contents entries and also to increase the space reserved for the number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Article~\thesection.}{1em}{}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}
\addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{1em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\section{Methods}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Took a little debugging to get the spacing right, but this fixed my problem, and is really simple.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the method described on p. 26f. of "The LaTeX Companion" to generate the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\makeatletter
%% The "\@seccntformat" command is an auxiliary command
%% (see pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.)
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
  {\csname the#1\endcsname\ }%   default
  {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
%% Put everything together by defining the macros 
%% '\...@seccntformat', where ... can be 'section', 
%% 'subsection', etc.
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{Article \thesection. }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Intro}
\section{Methods}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**: You've probably noticed that this method does *not* insert a period (full stop) after the Roman section number in the table of contents. (I'm not a fan of providing punctuation marks needlessly...) If you *do* require the dots following the Roman section numbers in the ToC, be sure load the `tocloft` package and issue the command `\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}` (in the preamble, of course). And, if you need the line of dots between the ToC-style section headers and the associated page numbers, you should issue the command `\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` after loading the `tocloft` package.

Comment: You may also wish to update the ToC entries to print a period after the number. Most likely a redefinition of `\numberline` using a similar technique or otherwise.

Comment: @Werner - I personally don't think it's good form to provide (unnecessary) periods. However, I'll provide a comment to show how one might add them to the ToC listing, if they're needed.

Comment: Good advice. One could include it for completeness, and reference your own personal style. Whichever you prefer...