# Sections without chapters in a LaTeX document

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

I have a document generated by doxygen with just `\section` directives and no chapters, so they're getting numbered as

```
0.1 Section 1
0.2 Section 2
0.2.1 SubSection 1
```

How can I skip the chapter number and display 1.1, 1.2, instead?

Comment: In some way, add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` to your preamble...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Your Mistake**

You are actually using the `book` or `report` class or something like that.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 1}

\end{document}
```

So, your output looks like this as reported by you.

[image]

**The Solution**

Please use the `article` class in place of `book` class.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 1}

\end{document}
```

The above gives your desired output.

[image]

**Relevant Explanations**

- `book` class is  for real books. And `article` class is for articles in scientific journals, presentations, short reports, program documentation, invitations.
- It is supposed that a book will contain chapters. Unless you specify a `\chapter` command at the start, your chapter number is zero, which is reflected in your output as you have told us. Please remember that `\chapter` command is not even recognized in  `article` class.
- To get a nice overview of the classes, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/book-vs-report-vs-article-document-class) is a must see.