# To make chapter bigger in article

Tags: formatting, chapters, article

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\chapter{RAA renal hormones} \label{06222014204556} \includepdf[pages={-}]{06222014204556.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I get formatting of **RAA renal hormones** as plain text.

If I change *documentclass* to *book*, then right format.

**What is the right way to make the chapter look like a heading in the article?**

Comment: The document class `article` doesn't provide the command `\chapter`: See [Regarding the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes: what are the main differences?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/regarding-the-book-report-and-article-document-classes-what-are-the-mai/36989#36989)

Comment: Do you mean the font size of chapter heading `RAA renal hormones`? Apart from the fact what Marco Daniel already mentioned, it is just `\section{\Huge RAA renal hormones}`. In `book.cls`, `\huge` and `\Huge` provide the same font size...

Comment: And your document is not compilable, as it contains a `\includepdf` command for a file not available to users here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is like Christian Hupfer implicitly writes: Change the `\chapter{RAA...}` to `\section{RAA...}`.

Your MNWE will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \section{RAA renal hormones} \label{06222014204556}
  \includepdf[pages={-}]{06222014204556.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If you want more easy options, I will suggest switching to the [KomaScript](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle. Then you can easily switch between small, medium and big headings, see page 86-88 in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.html).

```
\documentclass[headings=big,% or normal or small
               fontsize=12pt]% or 10pt or 11pt - 12pt give huge headings
  {scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \section{RAA renal hormones} \label{06222014204556}
  \includepdf[pages={-}]{06222014204556.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If you really want to add the word `Chapter` in front of the section number, and have the section title on its own line, i.e.

```
Chapter 1

RAA renal hormones

(text on new page)
```

you have to redefine the `section` command. That is an advance exercise.

Comment: As such you should at least `\Huge` to your solution ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I had not finished the proofing. :-]