# Vertical space between section and top of the page?

Tags: lyx

I'm writing my thesis in Lyx and I'm using the Article layout and I would like my section heading to be centred, always starting on a new page and to have some padding from the top of the page.

I have managed to get the section to be centred and to always start on a new page using this code in the Latex Preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\centering} 
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{\clearpage\stdsection}
```

However whats left is that I need to have a vertical space between the section heading and the top of the page and to increase the section heading font size slightly; so to make it easier to understand I want my sections to behave exactly like chapters in the example below:

[image]

Also if its possible I would like to increase the size of the section heading.

Anyone can help me out with how to do this? keeping in mind I have just started using Lyx a couple of days ago and I am very inexperienced with it so go easy on me!

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using this (sections to fake chapters)? It would be better to use a class (`book` or `report`, for example) providing proper chapters; the formatting can then be customized using `titlesec`, for example.

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. I think of a thesis like an article so I used the article class. Whats the main differences between article and book? is there any pros and cons for using one or the other?

Comment: Of course there are differences. A thesis is more likely to need proper chapters, each one with sections (some of them possibly with subsections). `book` offers you `\chapter` as the main sectional unit (besides `\part`); article doesn0t have `\chapter`. Try this simple document `\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}

\end{document}` and you'll see a big difference in formatting. There are some other differences, but comments are too short to discuss them.

Comment: See, for example, [Regarding the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes: what are the main differences?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/regarding-the-book-report-and-article-document-classes-what-are-the-mai).

Comment: Thanks! I just used report and its a lot more like what I'm looking for!

You should put your comments in to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of abusing sections to fake chapters it would be better to use a class (`book` or `report`, for example) providing proper chapters; the formatting for the chapter headings can then be easily customized (if required) using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, for example.

A thesis is more likely to need proper chapters, each one with sections (some of them possibly with subsections). `book` or `report` offer you `\chapter` as the main sectional unit (besides `\part`); `article` doesn't have `\chapter`. Try this simple document

```
\documentclass{book} 

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Test chapter} 
\section{Test section} 
\subsection{Test subsection} 
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection} 
\end{document}
```

and you'll see a big difference in formatting. There are some other differences; see, for example, the answer to [Regarding the `book`, `report`, and `article` document classes: what are the main differences?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988/3954).

There are also some alternative classes that you could consider using: `scrbook`, `scrreprt` or `memoir`.