# Prevent from starting a new page between list of figures and tables

Tags: tables, floats, lists

I used the following code:

```
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

However, for some reason it automatically starts a new page in between. I'm using `\documentclass{report}`. Before, I used document class `article` and it didn't happen, but I need to use report. Does anybody know how to get the list of figures and tables on the same page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is intended by the class `report` and I would not change this. But if you want to do that, you will find an example in the post I linked to.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah indeed it is a duplicate of that, I found the answer there. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, the only reason I'm using report now is because I need the "\chapter{blabla}" headings, for the rest I have no idea what's the difference between report and article? My whole text looks exactly the same (apart from some spacing and new page trouble on the first few pages)

Comment: Some lecture for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988