# Page numbering with \mainmatter and \frontmatter

Tags: page-numbering

I'm compiling my thesis want the initial page numbering to be roman and the following to be arabic. I divide the two sections using `\mainmatter` and `\frontmatter`. Any direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/Users/Amaan/Desktop/REPORT_Amaan_Ghole_v2/pics/}}
\usepackage[numbered, framed]{mcode}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\captionsetup{figurewithin=none}  
\captionsetup{tablewithin=none}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



   \pagestyle{fancyplain}
    \parskip=0cm
    \voffset=-0.54cm
    \hoffset=0.46cm
    \oddsidemargin=0pt
    \evensidemargin=0pt
    \topmargin=0pt
    \headheight=0.5cm
    \headsep=0.5cm
    \textheight=23.7cm
    \textwidth=15cm
    \setlength{\headwidth}{15cm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                         % copied from DCSSS04 style file to stop indenting paragraphs (the default)
%    \setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}    % copied from DCSSS04 style file, spaces paragraphs and titles
    \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}                          % makes a fixed space between paragraphs
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\lhead[\fancyplain{\thepage}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{\slshape \leftmark}{\slshape \leftmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{\slshape \leftmark}{\slshape \leftmark}]{\fancyplain{\thepage}{\thepage}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
%\setlength{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\setlength{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % real line

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{C&T_v2}
\include{abstract&ack_v2}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\include{acronyms_v2}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Intro_v2}
\include{LitRev_v2} 
\include{Kinematics_v2}
\include{Control_v2}
\include{smith_v2}
\include{Robust_v2}
\include{Comparison_v2}
\include{Simulations_v2}
\include{Conclusion_v2}

\appendix
\include{appendixA_v2}
\include{appendixB_v2}
\include{appendixC_v2}
\include{appendixD_v2}
\include{appendixE_v2}

\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{THESIS_v2}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your 'document' does not compile since it misses the `\documentclass` and there are a lot of `\include` statements for files we don't have access to.

Comment: sorry, I do include \documentclass and my document compiles. I'm not able to get the numbering correctly. I am able to include all the . tex files.

Comment: @AmaanGhole - You may have misunderstood Christian's comment. We have no doubt that *you* have a `\documentclass` instruction in your document and that *you* are able to include various tex files. The issue is that nobody else can do so and hence that the problem(s) your facing can't be replicated. For sure, please do share with us which document class you use.

Comment: Thank you,I use \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report} to write the thesis.

Comment: @AmaanGhole please update your question with this information

Comment: The commenters are asking you to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Please edit the code in your post to into a MWE.

Comment: Does `report` feature `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`? I don't think so.

Comment: Just use `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the places where you want the roman or arabic style to begin. This will reset the `page` counter.

Comment: Thank you this works , however, the arabic numbering begins one page before I  introduce \pagenumbering{arabic}, which is the last content page.

Comment: you might consider switching to the `book` class.  there are a few differences besides the presence of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, in particular the default to `twoside` (can be overruled by `[oneside]` as option to `\documentclass`) and the use of page headers (can be overruled by `\pagestyle{plain}`), but they shouldn't change the results radically.

Comment: To second babara's suggestion: you may want to read [this Q+A item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988/119) explaining the differences between book, article, and report.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192870)