# From `article` to `book` (in a modular document)

Tags: compiling, incompatibility, article, books

I am trying to compile a list of articles (in the sense that these texts are originally written and compiled using the `article` class) with the `book` class in a *modular* way.

However, for reasons not clear at all to me, the process does not work. Notice also that the articles, when compiled individually, do not create any problem.

> 1. Is it normal?
> 2. Should I check individually all the packages that I use and how they work with the `book`class?
> 3. If so, is there a rough guideline I can follow?
>      *(a reference concerning it would be greatly appreciated, i.e. some question or text online that points out at the incompatibilities between `articles` and `book`)*

An example of a problem I encounter is that, apparently, when moving from `article` to `book`, all the `\newcommand{...}{...}`do create problems.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

*PS: Please note that I am not posting a MWE because I consider the question as more general, and beyond a specific MWE. According to the answers or feedback I will proceed with giving a MWE in separate questions.*

Comment: Duplicate of  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/regarding-the-book-report-and-article-document-classes-what-are-the-mai?rq=1 ?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the [`combine` class](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf).

Comment: @Thruston: Thanks a lot for the link. Actually, I already noticed it, but I did not find much concerning the differences in coding. Thus, for example, the problem I have with `\newcommand` was not mentioned at all, and I have the feeling that it has to be a common issue, because right now I am having the same problem with the `combine` class (following TonioElGringo's feedback)

Comment: @TonioElGringo: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I immediately tried it, because it really looks like what I am looking for. However, as I mentioned in my previous comment to Thruston, apparently this class as well has problems with `\newcommand` which seems really puzzling to me.

Comment: There should *not* be any issues with new commands in general - so you will be unlikely to get any help here unless you can show us an example of a specific newcommand that works with `article.cls` and fails with `book.cls`.

Comment: @Thruston: Ok! Then it is really weird. Essentially, when I go on compiling, either with `book` or with `combine`, nothing works. I think I fixed the issues with the `newcommands`, because most probably these were single problems, but hypertargets or `newtheorem` just don't work.

Comment: @Thruston: Just for completeness. Indeed, as you wrote, there are no compatibility issues, *but* only when I put all the files together in a single file. When I proceed in a modular way, for reasons that I cannot understand, it does not work, and any sort of issues arise.