# how to add new thesis template in LYX

Tags: lyx, templates, thesis

I have used LYX for several months to write my paper and I really love this software. Next month, I am  going to write my thesis (using my school latex template). Now I had my friend thesis folders written by latex, it has a lot of .tex file, for example: mythesis.tex, frontpage.tex, table of content.tex, chapter1.tex, chapter2.tex and so on. 
I try to import it to LYX but it can not run properly.
Please help me add this thesis template into LYX. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does this template use a custom documentclass (i.e. is there a file with the extension `.cls` there)? The table of content and chapter files I would just ignore, make new files in LyX and include as child documents.

Comment: I agree with Torbjørn: most of the details of the templates are probably irrelevant to a LyX user. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328495/87201 for getting started with writing a thesis. If your school imposes further constraints on the look of the document I suggest implementing them afterwards, maybe by taking inspiration from the school template but without using the tex2lyx importation tool.

Comment: Help > Customization > 5 Installing New Document Classes