Setting up LaTeX for lecture notes. Which class is the most useful?
I have considered the classes report and book. I need to add the dates for each lecture(chapter). Is that possible for these specific classes?


Welcome to TeX.SE! The question is a bit too vague. What do you understand under "adding the date"? You can clearly write the date as part of the chapter title.

something like \date in article document class

Yes, it is possible. But be aware, that command date will give date of last compilation of your document. If I correctly understand you, you need to write date as ordinary text.

BTW, Which class is the most useful? is very opinion based.

ah gotcha thanks!

Welcome. // If it's still a question I suggest to put a simple mockup (sketch, best together eith code) of 2 or 3 lectures.

Edited to add a sketch

Thanks for the sketch. It seems to have some similarities with technical reports. Have a look here for one process to move from variables and content to layout: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722877/245790

Depends on your own familiarity with LaTeX, it may or may not be useful to look at some existing code (like my own lecture notes class; here's a set of lecture notes written using that class). But a lot of what you want can be done with titlesec and wrapper macros over \chapter. If you want to start from scratch I would suggest starting there.

For a comparison of classes see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36989/245790 . // As @WillieWong wrote, titlesec and article let you go a long way. // I suggest that you illustrate your use case(s) a bit more in your question, as implementation depends less on the class, and more on (in)conveniences available or imposed while your lectures progress. // Also your final goal may matter. E.g. do you plan to publish your collection of lectures later? Etc.

Here is some starter code. I used scrbook as the base class. You can change to any other class, it will still work. For lecture notes the date you give the lecture is not so important. Lectures normally come in a series. So I took a bit of a different view. If you really need the date, I would put it at the footer, but best is to issue a separate sheet for the lecture dates, classroom, times etc.. Most important is to define your requirements a bit better and write some code to start with. Use this as an opportunity to learn a bit more about LaTeX. There is no instant pizza when it comes to LaTeX, but here is half-a-slice!

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{lecture.sty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\def\pkgfamilyname{lecture}
\cs_if_exist:NTF \cxset{}{
\pgfkeys{/\pkgfamilyname/.is~family}
}
\newcommand\cxset{\pgfqkeys{/\pkgfamilyname}}
\definecolor{red1}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.9} 
\definecolor{blue1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1} 
\definecolor{green1}{rgb}{0.9,1,0.9} 
\definecolor{yellow1}{rgb}{1,1,0.8} 
\definecolor{yellow2}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{color11}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.6}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \lectureyear_tl
\cxset{
  lecture.author/.store~in = \lectureauthor_tl,
  lecture.year/.code   = \tl_set:Nn\lectureyear_tl{#1},
  lecture.series/.store~in = \lectureseries_tl, 
  lecture.series.title/.store~in =\lectureseriestitle_tl,
  lecture.color/.store~in =\lecturecolor_tl,
}

\cxset{
  lecture.author = H.\thinspace Thorn,
  lecture.year   = {2024-2025},
  lecture.series = E-210,
  lecture.series.title = Category Theory,
  lecture.color  = red1,
}

\newcounter{lecture}
\def\thelecture{\@Roman\c@lecture}

\NewDocumentCommand\lecture {+m} 
{
 \thispagestyle{plain}%
 \stepcounter{lecture}%
 \group_begin:
 \parindent0pt
  \fboxrule=0.1pt \relax
    \fboxsep=5pt \relax
  \bfseries 
 \hbox~to~\linewidth{\lectureseries_tl :\space \lectureseriestitle_tl \hfill\tl_use:N\lectureauthor_tl,~\tl_use:N\lectureyear_tl}\par
    \vspace*{20pt}
    
    \colorbox{\lecturecolor_tl}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth-10pt}{
        {\Large {\bfseries Lecture:\csname thelecture \endcsname\space #1}}}
        } 
   \vspace{2mm} 
  \par
  \group_end:
  \par\vskip20pt        
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading

}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff  
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Charis SIL}[
   Scale             = 1,
   Ligatures         = {Common,NoRare},
   SmallCapsFeatures = {RawFeature=+c2sc},
   Renderer          = Node,
   Numbers           = Lining,
   %RawFeature={fallback=panunicode},
  ]
 \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
 
\usepackage{lecture}
\begin{document}
\cxset{lecture.color=color11}
\noindent\lecture{Important theorems}
\paragraph*{Overview}\lipsum[1-2]

\bigskip
\noindent\lecture{The pigeon principle}
\paragraph*{Overview}\lipsum[3]
\end{document}

